# Intersect mesh and a flat surface in Rhinoceros

Tags: 3d

I have a big mesh object and I'd like to generate a line that copies the intersection between my mesh and a flat surface that passes through that mesh.

I cannot convert mesh to polysurface. I tried and my computer crashed after Rhinoceros explicitly warned me that it might crash.

Is there other method?

Comment: Splitting a mesh is somewhat trivial to do after all your graphics card does this many millions of times every second. You can simply just take each triangle at a time and intesectthat with the plane and create line if there is a intersection.

Answer (score 0):

I have only tried Rhino, but generally I use freeware. The same problem in there except not even possible to try convert a mesh to surface. But my shapes are extremely simple and I found 2 workarounds

- draw manually a spline through the available cutting points or
- convert also the surface to a mesh, split with it and draw a spline along the edge

The spline can be projected onto the original surface and used for trimming

Unfortunately these are practical only for simple shapes.

The following should be possible, but I have not used it:

Import a heavily decimated (=simplified) version of the mesh and try with it. Alternatively slice your mesh smaller with planes or other simple meshes in a proper mesh based program, leave only the needed part for the intersection.